# Why when I restart Ubuntu, Windows 11 Boots Instead?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Windows 11 is installed on my internal Laptop SDD,  and I have an external one that I installed Ubuntu on it.

When I start the Laptop for the first time it enters the grub and I get to choose which OS I need to open.

But when I restart Ubuntu, I get a black screen with blinking dash on it, and I can't do anything until an amount of time passes, then Windows boots instead of Ubuntu.

What I am trying to do is to make Ubuntu restart again normally.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that someone used Boot-Repair, so I tried it and used the recommended repairs and the grub loads every time I restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can change what will be booted by default in `/etc/default/grub` config file. (you can open it via `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and modify, you change `GRUB_DEFAULT=` value)

Then just execute `sudo update-grub`.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Comment: How would one do this if the machine loads Windows?